# Pairwise appending in python without ZIP

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

I am currently learning list comprehension in Python. How would I do the following:

```
l1 = [2,4,6,8]
l2 = [2,3,4,5]
l = [*some list comprehension*]
```

so that

```
l = [[2,2],[4,3],[6,4],[8,5]]
```

EDIT: Can I do this without zip?

Comment: Well to make it simpler for you `[[i,j] for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]`

Comment: Of course you can do it without `zip` but it is a very bad way to do `[[l1[i],l2[i]] for i in range(len(l1))]` ... ;)

Comment: So is it good programming practice to use zip? Also, is list comprehension good programming practice?

Comment: Of cause it is. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: You can also use `enumerate()` instead of `range()`

Comment: Now suppose I wanted to do division of the ith element by the ith element. Is the best code: [x/y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)] ?

Comment: Yes you certainly *can* do it without zip, but why would you intentionally not use a built-in function that was designed specifically to do what you're trying to do?

Comment: @skrrgwasme I am new to python and just created my own exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Example -

```
>>> l1 = [2,4,6,8]
>>> l2 = [2,3,4,5]
>>>
>>> l = list(zip(l1,l2))
>>> l
[(2, 2), (4, 3), (6, 4), (8, 5)]
```

If you want the inner lists to be of type `list` instead of tuple -

```
>>> l = [list(x) for x in zip(l1,l2)]
>>> l
[[2, 2], [4, 3], [6, 4], [8, 5]]
```

In python 3.x, `zip` returns an iterator, so if you do not want a list, but just want to iterate over each combined (zipped) element, you can just directly use - `zip(l1,l2)` .

As it is asked in the question, to do it without `zip` function, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to get the index as well as the element from one list and then use the index to get the element from second list.

```
>>> l = [[x,l2[i]] for i,x in enumerate(l1)]
>>> l
[[2, 2], [4, 3], [6, 4], [8, 5]]
```

But this would not work unless both lists have same size.Also not sure why you would want to do it without zip .

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> l1 = [2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> l2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
[[2, 2], [4, 3], [6, 4], [8, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` as

```
>>> l1 = [2,4,6,8]
>>> l2 = [2,3,4,5]
>>> zip(l1,l2)
[(2, 2), (4, 3), (6, 4), (8, 5)]
>>> [ list(x) for x in zip(l1,l2) ]
[[2, 2], [4, 3], [6, 4], [8, 5]]
```